# How can I use the capturing group in a function?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regex

`=REGEXREPLACE("string", "(ng)", UPPER("$1"))`

The above returns "string", but should return "striNG".

I suspect that this is because `UPPER` is capitalizing the string "$1" rather than the string with the captured group substituted into it.

How can I make `REGEXREPLACE` output the expected result?

Answer (score 4):

You could try splitting this into two parts returning the latter part as upper. Not sure how to nest the upper inside the regex in Gsheets.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"stri") & upper(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(ng)"))
```

this returned for me:

string > striNG

Answer (score 2):

it will highly depend on actual data, but these works too for **`string`**

```
=REGEXREPLACE("stri"&UPPER("ng"); "(ng)"; "$1")
```

---

```
=REGEXREPLACE("string";"(n)";"")&
 UPPER(REGEXREPLACE("string";"([a-z]{4})";"")
```

---

```
=LEFT(REGEXREPLACE("string";"(w)";"$1");4)&
 UPPER(RIGHT(REGEXREPLACE("string";"(w)";"$1");2))
```

all returns: **`striNG`**

Answer (score 2):

this will replace **`ng`** with **`NG`** in the word **`string`** or any other  word consisting of **`ng`**

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE("string"; "(ng)"; "NG"); "[a-zA-Z]{1,}")
```

this formula will do the same, but it uses **`UPPER()`** to do so:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE("string"; "(ng)"; UPPER("ng")); "[a-zA-Z]{1,}")
```

this formula provides a little bit more flexibility by using **`RIGHT()`** and specifying capital characters:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE("string"; "(ng)"; RIGHT(UPPER("string"); 2)); "[a-zA-Z]{1,}")
```

and this final formula is able to take any word and also it's fully adjustable by specifying how many characters from the right side to the end of the word should be `CAPS`ed:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE("string";
                     RIGHT("string";  2);
               RIGHT(UPPER("string"); 2)); "[a-zA-Z]{1,}")
```

[image]